# Typeing an Unicode charatcter using autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey, unicode, characters

How can I use AotoHotKey to replace `rRR` with `U+200E` character?

I tried `::rRR::Send {U+200F}` and  `::rRR::{U+200F}` but they do not works.

Comment: What version of AHK? If you can use the current version of AHK_L, I believe that one has Unicode script support - so you can embed the Unicode characters directly into the script.

Comment: @Bob I am using 1.1.08.1 version. I have no problem with embedding visible character directly in my script. But I this is an invisible character.